# Bundled So-Simple Jekyll theme not running in localhost with jekyll serve?

Tags: responsive-design, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am making a website for my girlfriend on her birthday as i cant be with her on that day.
I am using So-Simple Jekyll theme for the site but its not working somehow and not opening in local host. Its throwing the following error.

```
$ jekyll serve --watch
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  listen (~> 2.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.1/bin/jekyll:21:in `block in <top (required)>': cannot load such file -- jekyll/version (LoadError)
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:18:in `program'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.1/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

If you can help me please do as i have couple of days left for her birthday. Moreover any more birthday gift suggestions are welcome. Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I met the same error, you can run Jekyll with `bundled exec` instead.

```
bundle exec jekyll build

bundle exec jekyll serve
```

`bundle exec`: Run the command in context of the bundle.

> In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work, if
>   the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not
>   pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle.
>
> However, this is unreliable and is the source of considerable pain.
>   Even if it looks like it works, it may not work in the future or on
>   another machine.

It works for me, if you still met the error, please give more detail info.